# Should I use a const &iterator, or just an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, pass-by-reference

In order to help avoid unnecessary heap allocations of strings inside a class, I have adopted a pattern similar to the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    template<typename Iter>
    void GetName(Iter iter) const     // Allow for caller to provide the buffer
    {
        const char *name = ...;  // Get the name
        size_t cchName = ...;  // Get the size
        copy(&name[0], &name[cchName], iter);
    }

    string GetName() const            // Convenience method
    {
        string name;
        this->GetName(inserter(name, name.end()));
        return name;
    }
};
```

However, the code also seems to work perfectly fine when I say

```
    void GetName(const Iter &iter) const     // <----- changed to const &
```

Is there any reason (performance or otherwise) for me to use a `const &` version of the iterator, or should I just use `Iter` itself? (I don't know the convention for iterators, or if there are any implications.) (C++03)

Comment: Most iterator types have extremely simple inline-able copy constructors and destructors, so it's unlikely to make an important difference.  But I'm interested to see if there are any factors I didn't think of.

Comment: @aschepler: Yeah. Also, it's not just the *cost* of argument passing I'm worried about (the compiler is pretty smart about inlining, like you mentioned), but also wondering if there are any cases in which it might break, because of the `const`-ness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is same difference as pass by value and pass by reference while calling functions.

When you pass by value an copy of the passed variable gets created and the function uses it.

When you pass by reference, the copy is not made. Also, passing the type as `const` guards it against modification to some level(ofcourse hackery can break it).

Since In your code example you do not need to iterate using the iterator and just need to pass it to `std::copy` which creates its own copy, So your iterator being a `const` doesn't matter to it, Hence passing by const reference is better option in your example.

Comment: Well, I understand pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference, but are there any semantic issues on what `const` iterators can/should/shouldn't do that I don't know about? (Otherwise, how is it different from a regular iterator?)

Comment: It is not always better.  Actually, for most iterators, it is _slower_, since many iterators are simply pointers underneath, which means a pass by reference is the same number of bytes/copy, except it also requires a pointer dereference.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Do not mistake a `const_iterator` for a `const iterator`.  The first is a mutable iterator to constant data, and the second is a constant iterator to mutable data.  Very very different.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Right, I think I understand. But then how is an `iterator` different from a `const` `iterator`, if they are both modifiable (since they can both change their positions)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: How is an `int` different than a `const int`? same applies to iterator it as an type too.

Comment: @Als: I don't understand. If an `iterator` is `const`, then it can't change its position, right? (Otherwise the iterator would change state.) So the code shouldn't compile. That's why I'm feeling I'm missing some subtle semantic difference -- could my code break at some point?

Comment: One example: given `const iterator iter;`, you cannot do `++iter`.  But this doesn't hurt your function because `std::copy` probably (must?) takes its third iterator by value.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Ofcourse, you will need to consider what actions your code will perform.You cannot have one generalized rule for every scenario.You will have to deduce a rule depending on what the scenario is.In your example you do not change the iterators position,so it won't give an compilation error.

Comment: @Mehrhad: In the code in the question, `GetName` passes the iterator to `copy`, which makes it's own copy of the iterator.  `copy` requires a iterator to mutable data, but it doesn't matter if the iterator itself is `const` or not, since `copy` makes it's own non-const copy of the iterator.  Both forms of your code are perfectly safe.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Ooooh, I didn't realize that `copy` makes a copy of the iterator too! Thanks a lot, that answers my question!